# symfony how to use custom validators.yml file under MyBundle\Resources\translations

Tags: forms, validation, symfony-forms, symfony

On symfony3, I implement a custom form (no FosUserBundle is used on purpose because I go PDO instead of ORM to manage my DB).

On that form I want error message to be displayed.

It does work but **use the default "translators.[lang].xlf" file** which is **under the folder**: **[MyProject]\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Validator\Resources\translations.**

I added a **"validators.[lang].yml" file under the directory: [MyProject]\src\[MyBundle]\Resources\translations:** **It doesn't work**. I have some "messages.[lang].yml" files under that same directory and those work.

So I guess that I am missing something to have the "validators.[lang].yml" under "MyBundle" being recognized.

I see that in the symfony translation cookbook describes a way to add some extra catalog, but I don't get where it is supposed to be done -which file under which symfony folder?

**I would have thought that this could have been automated as soon as a  validators.[lang].yml file had been placed under the directory [MyProject]\src[MyBundle]\Resources\translations**, or a setting to do in the config.yml.

Does anyone have an experience to share about that?

Comment: This question is pretty useless because is a simple user carelessness  (very very frequent). It would be better to delete the question instead to post a link to the documentation in the answer. PS: it was better to read more carefully the docs BEFORE to post here an answer 13 minutes after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad...

After I had added  "validators.[lang].yml" file under the directory: [MyProject]\src[MyBundle]\Resources\translations.

**I should have done a "[MyProject]\ php bin/console cache:clear".**

It is explained here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#book-translation-resource-locations